# How do I migrate my heroku database?

Tags: database, migration, heroku

I've tried:

`heroku rake db:migrate`

and

`heroku pg:push`

The first gives me a PGerror / rake aborted error.

Is there a way to completely rebuild/reset my database with heroku? I can't seem to find it in their documentation.

EDIT: I had a working database before this, but my tables and relationships have changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you had a working database, you could recreate your tables from the schema:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

If you want to just reset the database to empty:

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

What is the error it is giving you? It might be more helpful to try to solve that problem rather than wipe everything.

Comment: Looks like heroku `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` then `heroku rake db:create` allowed me to recreate the database. Thank you @oded-harth and @felix

Comment: `heroku rake` has been deprecated in favor of `heroku run rake`. At least, that's what the error message told me.

Answer (score 5):

This should be updated as `heroku rake` has been deprecated.  Use `heroku run rake` now.  See below, per command-line/stderr output, as of today (March 8, 2013):

---

Incorrect:

- PROMPT>`heroku rake db:migrate --app myApp`

> WARNING: 'heroku rake'` has been deprecated. Please use 'heroku run rake' instead.
>
> ---

Correct:

- PROMPT>`heroku run rake db:migrate --app myApp`

> Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2810

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 heroku rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

This will get your database to its starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can make heroku run directly into Heroku webapp

[image: heroku command]

and then `heroku run rails db:migrate`

[image: heroku run rails db:migrate]

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run rake db:migrate -a appname
```

Comment: Explain your code, please. The code itself does not say much.