# Heroku error message: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a problem running a Rails app on Heroku.

I made the app from the Rails tutorial [Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) wrote. When I load the page I get:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Basic information logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error :Error (PG::Error :Error: syntax error at or near ")"
count_column FROM "microposts"
```

my trouble in views/pages/home.html.erb,.  my others pages no problem.. maybe in partial layout or page  ,. I don't known. click here this's [my Application](http://lit-gorge-8599.herokuapp.com/)

in this app, page home as root path is successfully appears but if I sign in, page home appears heroku message

> We're sorry, but something went wrong

views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>`
<table class="profile" summary="For signed-in users">
<tr>
<td class="sidebar round">
<h1 class="micropost">What's up?</h1>
<%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
</td>
<td class="main">
<%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<% else %>
<h3>Welcome to rails App by example</h3>
<p>Find out your friend, happening, connect to people or some the activities, organization and more</p>
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", 'signup', :class => "signup_button round" %>
<% end %>
```

I am Running

> heroku logs -t

```
ActionView::Template::Error :Error (PG::Error :Error: relation "users" doest not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token"=...
```

Thanks before

Comment: Looks like a problem with Postgres and your SQL.

Comment: run on terminal: heroku logs -t, and post the error

Comment: You should try to reproduce the issue locally. Are you running Postgres in development?

Comment: in development I using SQLite

Answer (score 2):

seems you didn't run migration on heroku, try:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163804/how-do-i-migrate-my-heroku-database)